Every second item in python list is disappearing in flask app
I have a flask application (Python 3 / Flask 2.2.5) which I am doing a once-off import of data using a flask custom command, the data is being imported via an API.
As there are many thousands of items, I am first chunking the API requests into groups of 100 items. Each item has a unique ID which is an integer.
I am creating a python list of those integers which I want to first check to see if they already exist locally in the database, and if they do - remove them from the list before building the request.
When I iterate over the list I am seeing what appears to be every second item disappearing from the list causing them to be skipped by my local database check.
My list looks like:
print(type(items_list), items_list)
<class 'list'> [18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 25, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 178, 179, 180, 181, 182, 183, 184, 185, 186, 187, 188, 189, 190, 191, 192, 193, 194, 195, 196, 197, 198, 199, 200, 201, 202, 203, 204, 205, 206, 207, 208, 209, 210, 211, 212, 213, 215, 216, 217, 218, 219, 220, 221, 222, 223, 224, 225, 226, 227, 228, 229, 230, 231, 232, 233, 234, 235, 236, 237, 238, 239, 240, 241, 242, 243, 244, 245, 246, 247, 248, 249, 250, 251, 252, 253, 254, 255, 256, 257, 258, 259, 260]

If I then iterate over that list, I can see that every second item is missing, for example ID's 19, 21, 35, 37, etc are missing.
for z in items_list:
    print("TRYING", z)

TRYING 18
TRYING 20
TRYING 22
TRYING 34
TRYING 36
TRYING 38
TRYING 40
TRYING 42
TRYING 44
<snip>

I've tried running it manually via a flask shell, and the behavior is consistent with the above.
Thanks in advance.
Update/edit: For completeness, here is the code from routes.py (the custom command) and then the function. It appears that if I remove the line which checks to see if the DB entry exists, the problem goes away.
routes.py:
@blueprint.cli.command('test')
def test_cmd():
    items = [18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 25, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 178, 179, 180, 181, 182, 183, 184, 185, 186, 187, 188, 189, 190, 191, 192, 193, 194, 195, 196, 197, 198, 199, 200, 201, 202, 203, 204, 205, 206, 207, 208, 209, 210, 211, 212, 213, 215, 216, 217, 218, 219, 220, 221, 222, 223, 224, 225, 226, 227, 228, 229, 230, 231, 232, 233, 234, 235, 236, 237, 238, 239, 240, 241, 242, 243, 244, 245, 246, 247, 248, 249, 250, 251, 252, 253, 254, 255, 256, 257, 258, 259, 260]
    test_items(2, items)

Then in my function:
def test_items(market_id, items):
        # check if any of the items in the list are updated in the last 1320 minutes, remove them if so
        now = datetime.datetime.now(tz=pytz.utc)
        delta = datetime.timedelta(minutes=1320)
        print(type(items), items)
        for z in items:
            print("TRYING", z)
            i = Market.query.filter_by(item_id=z, market=market_id).first()
            if i:
                expiry = pytz.utc.localize(i.last_updated) + delta
                # if now is before expiry, remove from list
                if now < expiry:
                    items.remove(z)
        print("END OF LIST")


Can you provide a [mre] that illustrates how you’re performing this and demonstrates the issue you’re talking about?

This is not reproducible (put another way, when I loop over your list I don't skip any numbers!)

@esqew sure, i've updated the post. It seems to be related to querying the model, The first item works, the query is performed, and the next time the loop is run, the item is skipped. Rinse & repeat.
